# Windows Server 2008 R2 Forcing TLS 1.0 For ssl encryption

Tags: c#, .net, http, ssl

I'm running website https://blackteamcorp.pl with a custom .net http server and ssl  certificate set via `netsh http add sslcert ipport=x.x.x.x:443 certhash=thumbprint appid={guid}` .
The problem is that the Windows uses outdated TLS 1.0 for encryption.

How can I make Windows use TLS 1.2 (or later) instead?

Comment: Is TLS 1.2 [enabled](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a433/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) on the server?

Comment: The keys were missing so i guess it was disabled, added them and now rebooting.

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is end of life, so get rid of it as soon as you can please.

Comment: I have ESU bought (and i plan to purchase it as long as it's available), no need for "newer" windows that would cause me trouble i've never seen.